# Get value of first column, first row from table returned from stored procedure

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

Within Logic apps, to get a value from a table that is the result of a stored procedure call, a loop is required, as the table is effectively an array.

Is there a way to just reference the first cell in the returned data, without looping through it?

The value i require will always be in the first cell in the table, so id rather not have additional actions in the logic app to loop through the table.

Below is what is being returned by the "Execute Stored Procedure V2" action:

```
{
"properties": {
    "ResultSets": {
        "properties": {
            "Table1": {
                "items": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Column1": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "Column1"
                    ],
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
},
"type": "object"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this expression:

```
body('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][0]?['Column1']
```

[image]

This way can get the first item in your array.